# How do I use heic format in Android P?

Tags: heif, heic

HeifEncoder was seen and implemented.

"MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_IMAGE_ANDROID_HEIC);"

If you do this, the following error will occur.

> Blockquote

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to initialize image/vnd.android.heic, error 0xfffffffe
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1811)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MediaCodec.java:1777)
```

Is there a way to resolve the error?